# Eleminate "\u00a0" from a string in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I receive from the databse strings where I found special chars like
\n
\n\u00a0
\n

This causes a lot of empty lines in the output. I understood that these chars are special chars NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0) but I want to get rid of them.

I found a lot of code in the net reagrding this request like

```
$cleaned_string = str_replace(["\n", "\n\u00a0", "\\n"], "/n", $string);
```

or

```
$content = preg_replace("/\r\n/", "\n", $_POST['content']);
```

or

```
$clean_html_body = preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/', '', $html_body);
```

and other regex - but all those code does not change anything in my string - I get the same output as the input. So something must be wrong in my code.

I tried on https://regex101.com/ the expression \u00a0 which founds all matches. But soon as I combined them with commands like preg_replace or str_replace it fails again - the special char is not removed.

Not sure if my headers are a reason so I put this code in on a blank page:

```
// Sample string containing newlines and special characters
$string = "This is a string\n with newline\n\u00a0and special character\n";

// Replace occurrences of "\n", "\n\u00a0", and "\n" with "/n"
$cleaned_string = str_replace(["\n", "\n\u00a0", "\\n"], "/n", $string);

// Output the cleaned string
echo $cleaned_string;
```

The code produces

```
This is a string/n with newline/n\u00a0and special character/n
```

So it changes the /n but not that special char \u00a0. Then I tried

```
preg_replace('#\R+#', '<br>', $string);
```

which gave me some line breaks as it replaces the \n but the '\u00a0' remains.
I am clueless now, any ideas?

Comment: If [this](https://3v4l.org/SNv7O) doesn't represent your actual data, please clarify the multibyte string is not actually literal characters that merely resemble the multibyte/unicode character expression.

Answer (score 0):

For the `NO-BREAK SPACE` you can use `preg_replace()` with the appropriate Unicode flag (`u`):

```php
$string = "This is a string\n with newline\n" . "\xC2\xA0" . "and special character\n";

$cleaned_string = preg_replace('/\xC2\xA0/', '', $string);
$cleaned_string = preg_replace("/\n/", "/n", $cleaned_string);

echo $cleaned_string;
```

Comment: Please do not prevent the Roomba from doing its job by posting answers to new duplicate questions.  If you have new, unique, value insights to add to Stack Overflow, please post them on the dupe target, not this page.  By Googling `php remove \u00a0 from string` I found the dupe target as the top result.  Please put more effort into serving the community better.

Comment: Hello Marcin, thank you for the help. If I parse the input from DB with json_encode to see the chars I have this as input: "Hello,
\n
\n\u00a0
\n
\na test 
\nfor special chars!
\n
\n\u00a0
\n
\nRegards"
After cleaning with your code I receive:
"Hello,
\n
\n
\n
\na test 
\nfor special chars!
\n
\n
\n
\nRegards" - so yes, the special chars are gone but I still have a lot of empty lines - now starting with a /n - how could I reduce this so that instead of "\n
\n\u00a0
\n" I only have one line break?

Comment: it might be tricky to do this in one call (you need to check) but you can always `explode()` your string into separate lines, iterate over exploded array, `trim()` each row and see if previous one was already empty. If not, put that in new array. Once you done with all rows, `implode()` that new array.